# change property of a group of buttons

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, visual-studio-2012, user-interface

WPF VB.NET

I have a customized control templated expander menu. Each menu item has some child buttons which will open its own page.
Example shown.

```
                -----------------------------------
                |   FILE   |   EDIT   |   TOOLS   |
                -----------------------------------
                FILE Menu has child items Button A1, A2, A3, A4
                EDIT Menu has child items Button B1, B2
                TOOLS Menu has child item Button C1
```

What i need is to change the foreground color of the child buttons based on Mouse selection.

When i select Button A1 (obviously Page of A1 opens), the foreground color of Button A1 should change. Say from white to Green.

Then menu bar collapses. when i go back & check the file menu again the color of Button A1 should be green. and should be disabled

Then when i Select button C1 (page of C1 opens), then the foreground color of C1 should change to green, button being disabled and the foreground color of A1 should change back to white and being enabled.

this is applicable for all child buttons in the menu bar.

How to make this possible in XAML.

Kindly suggest in xaml if it can be done in xaml itself. Else VB.Net

Comment: That is a scenario using Triggers: Use the MenuItem's "Checked" / "IsCheckable" Property to color your MenuItem's control (commonly a Label or TextBlock)

Comment: Plz try to understand what is asked before marking as duplicate.